# Create Foreign Key of ID in Odoo Model Tables

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I have two models defined in Odoo. The first model has an ID which automatically created by Odoo when i created a record in it. And then, I need to "link" that ID into my second models once i create it, with the name of `main_id`. This `main_id` will act as foreign key in second model.

I see that same approach is achieved between Odoo's `product.template` and `product.product` through `psql`. I can use One2Many to achieve this way, but i don't know how to define the field in Odoo to achieve `main_id` column that linked to `id` because i don't define the `id` by myself.

My First Model :

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'first.model'

    user = fields.Many2one("res.user", "Person Name")
    product_lines = fields.One2many('first.model.lines', 'product_id')
```

My Second Model :

```
class SecondModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'first.model.lines'

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="Product Name")
    product_qty = fields.Integer(string="Qty")
```

How can I create record in the second model that later has the First Model id as foreign key?

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is very similar to Sale order and Sale order Lines. 
Create a field `first_model_id OR  main_id = fields.Many2one("first.model")` in the first.model.lines model 
This field is also necessary to create the One2many field in first.model as One2many is actually relying on the Many2one relation.
In Odoo you might need to understand ORM concepts to completely understand how it works this [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#relational-fields) might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for creating a "Foreign Key" in One2many.

When creating One2many, as [Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html?highlight=one2many#odoo.fields.One2many) stated it needs something called `inverse_name`. It should be declared in first model and also the second model. Instead using `'product_id'`, i create a new variable named `'foreign_key'` that later will connect both model as it supposed be.

So the FirstModel would be :

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'first.model'

    user = fields.Many2one("res.user", "Person Name")
    product_lines = fields.One2many('first.model.lines', 'foreign_key')
```

and the SecondModel will be :

```
class SecondModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'first.model.lines'

    foreign_key = fields.Many2one('combine.product', string="Foreign Key")
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="Product Name")
    product_qty = fields.Integer(string="Qty")
```

As addition, since `foreign_key` will be automatically added by Odoo, inside .XML files, i hide that `foreign_key` field so user will not notice and doing things on it.

My XML file :

```
<field name="product_lines">
   <tree>
      <field name="foreign_key" invisible="1"/>
      <field name="product_id"/>
      <field name="product_qty"/>
   </tree>
</field>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a **Many2one** relational field in your first model line and then use it in the **One2many** field in the first model as follows:

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
_name = 'first.model'

# One2many of the lines (main_id is a foreign key in the first.model.line)
line_ids = fields.One2many('first.model.lines', 'main_id', 'Lines')


class FirstModel(models.Model):
_name = 'first.model.lines'

# Foreign Key of the first.model
main_id = fields.Many2one('first.model', 'First Model')
```

Comment: Thank you Sudhir Arya! it working great but user are needed to assign this everytime they are creating record in first.model.lines, do you have idea how to make it "default-ly" same?

Comment: Ohh nevermind i figured it, it's using context.

Comment: If you use `line_ids` in the formular view of `first.model` you don't have to provide `main_id`, because Odoo will fill it on creation itself.

Comment: @CZoellner do i have to define `line_ids` by myself in first.model, e.g. line_ids = fields.Integer() to make it automatically assigned to second.model? Could you elaborate on new answer please? Because currently i use a context provided by client side to create foreign key and perhaps using this `line_ids` would be better answer related to the question? :D